# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/main.js' Vue 3 on Rails

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, heroku, vuejs3, webpacker

I'm trying to create an application with Rails and Vue 3. Everything works fine on my local host but when I try to push it on Heroku or when I type in my terminal "npm run build" I have this error message :

Error message (EDIT)

< error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/main.js' in
> '/home/reaven/ForHonorTeam'
>
> ERROR  Error: Build failed with errors. Error: Build failed with
> errors.
> at /home/reaven/ForHonorTeam/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/index.js:207:23
> at /home/reaven/ForHonorTeam/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:148:8
> at /home/reaven/ForHonorTeam/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:68:3
> at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/reaven/ForHonorTeam/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10),
> :6:1)
> at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/home/reaven/ForHonorTeam/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
> at Cache.shutdown (/home/reaven/ForHonorTeam/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:150:23)
> at /home/reaven/ForHonorTeam/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1225:15
> at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/reaven/ForHonorTeam/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10),
> :6:1)
> at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/home/reaven/ForHonorTeam/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
> at Compiler.close (/home/reaven/ForHonorTeam/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1218:23)

And this is what looks like my environment.js :

environment.js

[image: 2]

Finally, this is my repo structure :

Repo structure

[image: 3]

I've tried to find a solution in here but I did not find anything that helps me. Maybe I just failed to see something very important. I'm sorry if this issue is easy to solve.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please don't post links to errors, post the actual errors.

Comment: Sorry it is done now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where `vue-cli-service serve src/App.vue` would work but `vue-cli-service build` would not. It seems given no entry point, vue cli service assumes the presence of `./src/main.js` and fails if none is found. Providing the path to build works for me, e.g. similar to the serve use `vue-cli-service build src/App.vue` in the build task.

Adjust the path to your Vue app entry point.